# Que veut dire « étourdi » ?

Tags: vocabulaire

Quand dit-on que quelqu'un est *étourdi* ? Selon le Wiktionnaire, il faut que quelqu’un agisse sans réfléchir.

Qu’est-ce qu’une personne étourdie fait ? accomplit-elle un boulot ? essaie-t-elle d'écouter quelqu’un ? Le mot *étourdi* sous-entend-il que ce qu’elle fait requiert du soin, ou peut-on aussi faire quelque chose de façon étourdie et faire du bon travail quand-même, comme tourner une manivelle ou se promener à un endroit en sûreté ?

Pour un étourdi, quelle est la raison d'agir « sans réfléchir » ? Il s’endort presque, ou est-ce qu’il s’occupe de quelque chose ? Ou est-ce que ça veut plutôt dire que ce qui se déroule autour de lui le distrait facilement ?

Des réponses à ces questions apporteraient beaucoup de clarté. J’espère aussi que vous pouvez me fournir des exemples faciles pour mieux comprendre comment ce mot s’insère dans une conversation. Le Trésor de la langue française donne déjà beaucoup d’exemples mais comme souvent, ils sont un peu durs pour quelqu’un qui sait peu du français.

Comment: In case it helps, consider that it can translate to both *dizzy* and *absent-minded* in English. The causes and behaviors of those two can be quite different, but they have some behavior in common.

Comment: L’anglais n’est pas ma langue maternelle. Une traduction de français en anglais ne répondrait pas ma question, elle la déplacerait. Je connais le mot « dizzy », mais je n’ai jamais vu « absent-minded » ’anglais n’est pas ma langue maternelle.

Comment: La plupart du temps j'ai entendu *étourdi* utilisé dans le contexte de *déséquilibré* : `Après avoir tourné pendant 5 minutes sur ma chaise, j'étais très étourdi`. Au Québec, la vocation que tu donnes à ce mot est presque inexistant. C'est à voir pour le reste de la planète.

Comment: @KoenraadvanDuin: C'est pourquoi j'ai ecrit **In case it helps**: au cas ou ca peut vous aider.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Être *étourdi*, c'est être inattentif, se laisser distraire par le dernier événement, oublier une étape dans un raisonnement ou dans une procédure quelconque.

C'est aussi "Qui oublie, égare facilement, qui manque de mémoire et d'imagination" (Le Robert)

> Quelle *étourdie* ! Elle part faire son marché et oublie son porte-monnaie !
>
> Quel *étourdi* je suis ! J'ai préparé ma valise et me voilà au bord de la mer sans maillot de bain.
>
> Vous n'êtes qu'un *étourdi* : vous avez oublié le principe de réversibilité dans votre démonstration !

*Étourdi* a aussi le sens d'être légèrement assommé (sans perdre connaissance), affaibli par une situation physique ou émotionnelle intense.

> Ces manèges rapides m'ont complètement *étourdi*, je vacille sur mes jambes.
>
> Le cuisinier *étourdit* (assomme sans le tuer) l'animal d'un coup sur la nuque avant de le saigner.

Answer (score 1):

Les messages précédents indiquent la signification d'"étourdi" en tant que nom : "quel étourdi !", "vous êtes un étourdi". Vous pouvez aussi l'utiliser en tant qu'adjectif : "Elle est très étourdie aujourd'hui". La signification sémantique reste la même, et la connotation d'éphémère reste aussi.

Answer (score 0):

More usually it can be a synonym of distracted. (ex: 
A student who doesn't listen and thinks about something else;
or someone who always forgets things)

Comment: Original poster is French (as stated in a previous comment), refrein from posted an English answer as he won't understand what you say. || Celui qui a poser la question est Français (comme spécifié dans un commentaire si-haut), vous devriez écrire la réponse en français pour qu'il puisse vous comprendre.