# Comment améliorer la phrase « Quel étourdi je suis de penser que vous êtes allemand ! »

Tags: constructions

Il semble être plus dur qu’à ce que je me suis attendu de faire une phrase qui couvre les idées suivantes à la fois :

- Je pensais que vous étiez allemand.
- C’était bête de penser cela.
- désolé

Comment rédiger une telle phrase ?

---

**Ce que j’ai essayé moi-même**

J’ai pensé à

« Quel étourdi je suis de penser que vous êtes allemand ! »

Dont j’ai puisé la partie « quel étourdi je suis » [de cette réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11564/que-veut-dire-%C3%A9tourdi). Je ne sais pas si cette façon dire peut être étendue comme ci-dessus.

Mon deuxième choix serait :

« Je suis vraiment trop bête de penser que vous êtes allemand ! »

Ici je crains également d’unir des mots de façon tordue. Je pense que « Je suis vraiment trop bête » est assez usitée, mais peut-être est-ce plus argotique que je souhaite.

Et si ces choses ne se comprennent pas j’utiliserais

« Mais que je suis bête de penser que vous êtes allemand ! »

Comment: En général, il faut le subjonctif : « … que vous **soyez** allemand », parce qu'on sait que c'est faut. Je n'ai pas le temps de rédiger une réponse tout de suite, si quelqu'un veut le faire il/elle est le bienvenu(e).

Comment: Quel est le contexte ? Même si j'approuve les réponses données, je les trouves un brin trop formelles...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> « Quel étourdi je suis de penser que vous êtes allemand ! »

Tout à fait correct, peut être dit sur un ton enjoué, avec humour.

> « Je suis vraiment trop bête de penser que vous êtes allemand ! »

Tout à fait correct, peut être dit sur un ton de la culpabilité, du regret d'avoir proféré une phrase qui peut être prise pour une insulte.

> « Mais que je suis bête de penser que vous êtes allemand ! »

Tout à fait correct, peut être dit sur un ton énervé, lorsque l'on s'en veut, ou alors, en exagérant, en surjouant les mots (accentuation exagérée de *bêêête*) comme dans certaines comédies de boulevard où l'on 'gueule' les phrases en faisant de grands gestes.

En fait, le choix d'une des trois phrases se fera en fonction du contexte, et il y a mille et une façon d'exprimer cette exclamation :

> « Suis-je donc [vraiment] bête de penser que vous êtes allemand ! »
>
> « Suis-je bête ! vous allemand ? Quelle idée !  »
>
> « Avoir pensé que vous étiez allemand, quelle erreur ! »
>
> ...

Answer (score 0):

I would say this, rather than the above answers, as I find them very formals

> Je suis vraiment bête d'avoir pensé que tu **étais** allemand!
>
> Je suis vraiment bête d'avoir pensé que vous **étiez** allemand!